# Convert Python dict into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary:

```py
{u'2012-07-01': 391,
 u'2012-07-02': 392,
 u'2012-07-03': 392,
 u'2012-07-04': 392,
 u'2012-07-05': 392,
 u'2012-07-06': 392}
```

I would like to convert this into a pandas dataframe by having the dates and their corresponding values as two separate columns; the expected result looks like:

```
     Date         DateValue
0    2012-07-01    391
1    2012-07-02    392
2    2012-07-03    392
.    2012-07-04    392
.    ...           ...
```

Is there a direct way to do this?

Answer (score 854, accepted):

The error here, is since calling the DataFrame constructor with scalar values (where it expects values to be a list/dict/... i.e. have multiple columns):

```
pd.DataFrame(d)
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must must pass an index
```

You could take the items from the dictionary (i.e. the key-value pairs):

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame(d.items())  # or list(d.items()) in python 3
Out[11]:
             0    1
0   2012-07-02  392
1   2012-07-06  392
2   2012-06-29  391
3   2012-06-28  391
...

In [12]: pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])
Out[12]:
          Date  DateValue
0   2012-07-02        392
1   2012-07-06        392
2   2012-06-29        391
```

But I think it makes more sense to pass the Series constructor:

```
In [21]: s = pd.Series(d, name='DateValue')
Out[21]:
2012-06-08    388
2012-06-09    388
2012-06-10    388

In [22]: s.index.name = 'Date'

In [23]: s.reset_index()
Out[23]:
          Date  DateValue
0   2012-06-08        388
1   2012-06-09        388
2   2012-06-10        388
```

Comment: @user1009091 I realised what the error means now, it's basically saying "What I'm seeing is a Series, so use Series constructor".

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. Could you perhaps explain what's the difference between using this method and using DataFrame.from_dict() ? Your method (which I used) returns type = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, while the other returns type = class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'. Any chance you could explain the difference and when each method is appropriate? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: they are both similar, [`from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) has an orient kwarg, so I might use it if I wanted to avoid transposing. There are few options with `from_dict`, under the hood it's not really different from using DataFrame constructor.

Comment: I'm seeing `pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` from the first example

Comment: @allthesignals adding list() around d.items works: pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])

Comment: @AndyHayden why did you advocate the series over the item solution? Is it because the OP had a bazillion entries? First option worked for me, so thanks were given.

Answer (score 379):

When converting a dictionary into a pandas dataframe where you want the keys to be the columns of said dataframe and the values to be the row values, you can do simply put brackets around the dictionary like this:

```
>>> dict_ = {'key 1': 'value 1', 'key 2': 'value 2', 'key 3': 'value 3'}
>>> pd.DataFrame([dict_])
 
    key 1     key 2     key 3
0   value 1   value 2   value 3
```

EDIT: In [the pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) one option for the `data` parameter in the DataFrame constructor is a list of dictionaries. Here we're passing a list with one dictionary in it.

Comment: Yes I also did this but added .T to transpose.

Comment: It works fine but don't know why we have to do it like this.

Comment: what if i want one these column to be used as index

Answer (score 178):

As explained on another answer using `pandas.DataFrame()` directly here will not act as you think.

What you can do is use [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with **`orient='index'`**:

```
In[7]: pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({u'2012-06-08': 388,
 u'2012-06-09': 388,
 u'2012-06-10': 388,
 u'2012-06-11': 389,
 u'2012-06-12': 389,
 .....
 u'2012-07-05': 392,
 u'2012-07-06': 392}, orient='index', columns=['foo'])
Out[7]: 
            foo
2012-06-08  388
2012-06-09  388
2012-06-10  388
2012-06-11  389
2012-06-12  389
........
2012-07-05  392
2012-07-06  392
```

Comment: can we chain this with any `rename` method to also set the names of the index **and** columns in one go ?

Comment: good point. One example would be: ...., orient='index').rename(columns={0:'foobar'})

Comment: You can also specify pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(..., orient = 'index', columns = ['foo', 'bar']), this is from the [source listed above](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).

Comment: good point, this is true from pandas .22 which was after the original answer... Updated my answer...

Answer (score 86):

Pass the items of the dictionary to the DataFrame constructor, and give the column names. After that parse the `Date` column to get `Timestamp` values.

Note the difference between python 2.x and 3.x:

In python 2.x:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data.items(), columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

In Python 3.x: (requiring an additional 'list')

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(data.items()), columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Comment: This gives me: `PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Comment: @ChrisNielsen You are probably using python3. You should try: `df = pd.DataFrame(list(data.items()), columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])`

Comment: This is the better answer because it shows what must be done in Python 3.

Comment: Why you are using pd.DataFrame(list(data.items())) but other user suggests pd.DataFrame([data])?
Do we need items()?

Answer (score 69):

[image: df from lists and dictionaries]

p.s. in particular, I've found Row-Oriented examples helpful; since often that how records are stored externally.

https://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html

Answer (score 17):

Pandas have [built-in function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) for conversion of dict to data frame.

> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionaryObject,orient='index')

For your data you can convert it like below:

```
import pandas as pd
your_dict={u'2012-06-08': 388,
 u'2012-06-09': 388,
 u'2012-06-10': 388,
 u'2012-06-11': 389,
 u'2012-06-12': 389,
 u'2012-06-13': 389,
 u'2012-06-14': 389,
 u'2012-06-15': 389,
 u'2012-06-16': 389,
 u'2012-06-17': 389,
 u'2012-06-18': 390,
 u'2012-06-19': 390,
 u'2012-06-20': 390,
 u'2012-06-21': 390,
 u'2012-06-22': 390,
 u'2012-06-23': 390,
 u'2012-06-24': 390,
 u'2012-06-25': 391,
 u'2012-06-26': 391,
 u'2012-06-27': 391,
 u'2012-06-28': 391,
 u'2012-06-29': 391,
 u'2012-06-30': 391,
 u'2012-07-01': 391,
 u'2012-07-02': 392,
 u'2012-07-03': 392,
 u'2012-07-04': 392,
 u'2012-07-05': 392,
 u'2012-07-06': 392}

your_df_from_dict=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(your_dict,orient='index')
print(your_df_from_dict)
```

Comment: That is really bad solution, since is saves dictionary keys as index.

Comment: It's not a bad solution, maybe someone wants the dict key as the index. If you want the dict key as a regular column and not an index, then you can do extra steps, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe/58520351#58520351

Answer (score 17):

This is what worked for me, since I wanted to have a separate index column

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(some_dict, orient="index").reset_index()
df.columns = ['A', 'B']
```

Comment: This fixed so index was corrected for me

Answer (score 15):

```
pd.DataFrame({'date' : dict_dates.keys() , 'date_value' : dict_dates.values() })
```

Answer (score 12):

The point is how to put each element in a `DataFrame`.

Row-wise:

```py
pd.DataFrame(dic.items(), columns=['Date', 'Value'])
```

or columns-wise:

```py
pd.DataFrame([dic])
```

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way I found is to create an empty dataframe and append the dict.
You need to tell panda's not to care about the index, otherwise you'll get the error: `TypeError: Can only append a dict if ignore_index=True`

```
import pandas as pd
mydict = {'foo': 'bar'}
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(mydict, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 10):

This is how it worked for me :

```
df= pd.DataFrame([d.keys(), d.values()]).T
df.columns= ['keys', 'values']  # call them whatever you like
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

Accepts a dict as argument and returns a dataframe with the keys of the dict as index and values as a column.

```
def dict_to_df(d):
    df=pd.DataFrame(d.items())
    df.set_index(0, inplace=True)
    return df
```

Comment: take a dict, returns a data frame

Answer (score 6):

You can also just pass the keys and values of the dictionary to the new dataframe, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

myDict = {<the_dict_from_your_example>]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = myDict.keys()
df['DateValue'] = myDict.values()
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case I wanted keys and values of a dict to be columns and values of DataFrame. So the only thing that worked for me was:

```
data = {'adjust_power': 'y', 'af_policy_r_submix_prio_adjust': '[null]', 'af_rf_info': '[null]', 'bat_ac': '3500', 'bat_capacity': '75'} 

columns = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
arr_len = len(values)

pd.DataFrame(np.array(values, dtype=object).reshape(1, arr_len), columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

`%timeit` result on a common dictionary and `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` is the clear winner.

```
%timeit cols_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(clu_meta,orient='index',columns=['Columns_fromUser'])
214 µs ± 9.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.DataFrame([clu_meta])
943 µs ± 10.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.DataFrame(clu_meta.items(), columns=['Default_colNames', 'Columns_fromUser'])
285 µs ± 7.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can make some changes in your data format when you create dictionary, then you can easily convert it to DataFrame:

input:

```
a={'Dates':['2012-06-08','2012-06-10'],'Date_value':[388,389]}
```

output:

```
{'Date_value': [388, 389], 'Dates': ['2012-06-08', '2012-06-10']}
```

input:

```
aframe=DataFrame(a)
```

output: will be your DataFrame

You just need to use some text editing in somewhere like Sublime or maybe Excel.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'Date': list(yourDict.keys()),'Date_Values': list(yourDict.values())}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If you don't encapsulate `yourDict.keys()` inside of `list()` , then you will end up with all of your keys and values being placed in every row of every column. Like this:

`Date  \
0   (2012-06-08, 2012-06-09, 2012-06-10, 2012-06-1...

1   (2012-06-08, 2012-06-09, 2012-06-10, 2012-06-1...

2   (2012-06-08, 2012-06-09, 2012-06-10, 2012-06-1...

3   (2012-06-08, 2012-06-09, 2012-06-10, 2012-06-1...

4   (2012-06-08, 2012-06-09, 2012-06-10, 2012-06-1...`

But by adding `list()` then the result looks like this:

`Date  Date_Values
0   2012-06-08          388
1   2012-06-09          388
2   2012-06-10          388
3   2012-06-11          389
4   2012-06-12          389
...`

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this several times and have an example dictionary that I created from a function `get_max_Path()`,  and it returns the sample dictionary:

`{2: 0.3097502930247044,
 3: 0.4413177909384636,
 4: 0.5197224051562838,
 5: 0.5717654946470984,
 6: 0.6063959031223476,
 7: 0.6365209824708223,
 8: 0.655918861281035,
 9: 0.680844386645206}`

To convert this to a dataframe, I ran the following:

`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(get_max_path(2), orient = 'index').reset_index()`

Returns a simple two column dataframe with a separate index:

`index  0
0   2   0.309750
1   3   0.441318`

Just rename the columns using `f.rename(columns={'index': 'Column1', 0: 'Column2'}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If the **keys are meant to be a separate column**, then constructing a Series and then resetting index and renaming columns later does the job.

```py
d = {'2012-06-08': 388, '2012-06-09': 388, '2012-06-10': 388, '2012-06-11': 389}

df = pd.Series(d).rename_axis('Date').reset_index(name='Value')
df = pd.Series(d).reset_index().set_axis(['Date', 'Value'], axis=1)


         Date  Value
0  2012-06-08    388
1  2012-06-09    388
2  2012-06-10    388
3  2012-06-11    389
```

If the **keys are supposed to the index**, then constructing a Series and then expanding to a DataFrame does the job.

```py
df = pd.Series(d).to_frame('Value')


            Value
2012-06-08    388
2012-06-09    388
2012-06-10    388
2012-06-11    389
```

---

If the dictionary is deeply nested (resembling a json object), then you can also use `json_normalize()` to flatten it.

```py
d = {'id': 0, 'Data': [{'x': {'a': 10, 'b': 2}}, {'x': {'a': 20, 'b': 1}}]}
df = pd.json_normalize(d, 'Data', 'id')


   x.a  x.b id
0   10    2  0
1   20    1  0
```