# Mean of 30 most recent data points for each unique value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to get the mean of 30 most recent points in column `a` for each type of product specified in column `b` given a date column `c`.

So the calculation of the average will be based on the most recent 30 points of each particular `Product` as opposed to the overall most recent data points of the whole `DataFrame`.

```
df:

Product            Value      Date
POL Mumbai         22.5       2015-6-26
STOLCO Finesse     55.5       2015-7-1
MPLR  Pure         85.0       2015-8-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general terms, you could [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) your DataFrame assumed to be called `df` by its column 'b' like so:

```
products = df.groupby('b)
```

then iterate through each product group as follows:

```
mean = {}
for product, data in products:
    mean[product] = data.sort('c', ascending=False).head(30)['a'].mean()
print DataFrame.from_dict(mean.items(), columns=['Product', 'Mean')
```

or

```
print Series(mean)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe) for details on the error you encountered.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I tried this but I must be doing something wrong. Error is "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index".

Comment: Hi, could you pls share what your data, esp your 'products' look like?

Comment: Just added example format in the original question. 
Cheers

Comment: Thanks - updated my answer, let's see if this works.