# Converting a Dictionary into a Dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, format

i have a Dictionary which has key value pairs like below

`dict= ('P06', 'P09'): 36340, ('P01', 'P05', 'P06', 'P09'): 10085, ('P01', 'P06'): 36337, ('P01', 'P09'): 49897, ('P02', 'P09'): 11573.....`

I want it to be converted into a Dataframe of the below format

`Product Id                        Count    Lenght
('P06', 'P09')                     36340      2
('P01', 'P05', 'P06', 'P09')       10085      4
('P01', 'P06')                     36337      2`

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Python dict into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
dict= {('P06', 'P09'): 36340, ('P01', 'P05', 'P06', 'P09'): 10085, ('P01', 'P06'): 36337, ('P01', 'P09'): 49897, ('P02', 'P09'): 11573}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index')

df.rename_axis('Product Id').reset_index()\
  .assign(length = df.index.str.len()).rename(columns={0:'Count'})
```

Output:

```
             Product Id  Count  length
0            (P06, P09)  36340       2
1  (P01, P05, P06, P09)  10085       4
2            (P01, P06)  36337       2
3            (P01, P09)  49897       2
4            (P02, P09)  11573       2
```