# pandas/numpy: I have an array with a dictionary inside. How do I create a DataFrame from this?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'one':[1,1,1,1,1],'two':[2,2,2,2,2],'letter':['a','a','b','b','c']}
e = np.array(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(e)
```

Throws this error:

```
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

Comment: Pass it as a list i.e 
    `df = pd.DataFrame(e.tolist())`

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html - Do you have a specific question about how that doco relates to what you are doing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `e=np.array(d)`. The `data` parameter in the dataframe constructor accepts properly formatted dictionaries.

Just use

```
df = pd.Dataframe(d)
```

Output:

```
  letter  one  two
0      a    1    2
1      a    1    2
2      b    1    2
3      b    1    2
4      c    1    2
```

Comment: But if I wanted to use an array to do so, how would I do that?