# Adding columns to a dataframe using a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe `df1`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1],
                    'c2': [2],
                    'c3': [3]})
```

I want to add columns to this dataframe using a dictionary `dict`

```
my_dict = {'c4': 4, 'c5': 5}
```

so I ultimately want `df1` to become

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1],
                    'c2': [2],
                    'c3': [3],
                    'c4': [4],
                    'c5': [5]})
```

What I have found on SO is only example where a dictionary is turned into a DataFrame along the rows, e.g. this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe) - and not along columns as in the above question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df1.join(pd.DataFrame([my_dict]))
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame([my_dict])], axis=1)

print (df)
   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`pd.DataFrame.assign`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) unpacking the dictionary into keyword arguments.

```
df1.assign(**my_dict)

   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0   1   2   3   4   5
```