# Convert Python dict of Arrays into a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary of arrays like the following:

```
d = {'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4], 'c': [5,6]}
```

I want to create a pandas dataframe like this:

```
   0      1      2
0  a      1      2
1  b      3      4
2  c      5      6
```

I wrote the following code:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()))
```

which returns:

```
   0    1      
0  a  [1,2]      
1  b  [3,4]      
2  c  [5,6]
```

Do you know how can I achieve my goal?!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python dict into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pandas allows you to do this in a straightforward fashion:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient = 'index')
>>      0   1
    a   1   2
    b   3   4
    c   5   6
```

`pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient = 'index').reset_index()` gives you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Use the **`splat`** operator in a comprehension to produce your dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame([k, *v] for k, v in d.items())

   0  1  2
0  a  1  2
1  b  3  4
2  c  5  6
```

If you don't mind having **`index`** as one of your column names, simply transpose and **`reset_index`**:

```
pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index()

  index  0  1
0     a  1  2
1     b  3  4
2     c  5  6
```

Finally, although it's rather ugly, the most performant option I could find on very large dictionaries is the following:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()), index=list(d.keys())).reset_index()
```