# Convert Dictionary to Dataframe having nested list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say, I have a dictionary like below

```
sample_dict= { 'A':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
               'B':[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],
               'C':[[13,14,15]]}
```

I would like to convert this dictionary to dataframe like below.

**Expected Output:**

```
|----------------|-------------|------------|----------|
|      keys      |     col1    |    col2    |   col3   |
|----------------|-------------|------------|----------|
|       A        |      1      |      2     |     3    |
|----------------|-------------|------------|----------|
|       A        |      4      |      5     |     6    |
|----------------|-------------|------------|----------|
|       B        |      7      |      8     |     9    |
|----------------|-------------|------------|----------|
|       B        |      10     |      11    |     12   |
|----------------|-------------|------------|----------|
|       c        |      13     |      14    |     15   |
|----------------|-------------|------------|----------|
```

while performing this below code

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict,orient='index')
df
```

I'm getting the resultant output as:

```
|----------------|-------------|--------------|
|                |     0       |    1         |
|----------------|-------------|--------------|
|       A        |   [1,2,3]   |   [4,5,6]    |
|----------------|-------------|--------------|
|       B        |   [7,8,9]   |  [10,11,12]  |
|----------------|-------------|--------------|
|       C        | [13,14,15]  |     None     |
|----------------|-------------|--------------|
```

Ideas are welcome!!

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
import pandas as pd

sample_dict = {'A': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
               'B': [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]],
               'C': [[13, 14, 15]]}


df = pd.DataFrame([[k, *v] for k, vs in sample_dict.items() for v in vs], columns=["keys", "c1", "c2", "c3"])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  keys  c1  c2  c3
0    A   1   2   3
1    A   4   5   6
2    B   7   8   9
3    B  10  11  12
4    C  13  14  15
```

If the number of columns is not known before hand, do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[k, *v] for k, vs in sample_dict.items() for v in vs]) \
    .rename(columns=lambda x: "c" + str(x)) \
    .rename(columns={"c0": "keys"})
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dani, This really worked!...Really appreciated for the work!

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want from stackoverflow question [Look at accepted awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315083/convert-python-dict-of-arrays-into-a-dataframe)

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict,orient='index').reset_index
```

Comment: This code makes my keys as index and getting different columns for each list of values for that specific key...and answer provided by dani was helpful for my problem...Really appreciated for your effort!..Thanks a lot.