# Creating dataframe objects from a dictionary using 'for' loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has `dataframes` in values, something like this -

```
dict = {'demand': demand_df, 'supply':supply_df, 'prod': prod_df}
```

then, 
I have a list like this -

```
list = ['demand', 'supply', 'prod']
```

I want to create individual `dataframes` objects using a loop, resulting in below -

```
demand = demand_df
supply = supply_df
prod =  prod_df
```

My try -

```
for i in list:
   i = dict[i]
```

This obviously is giving an error. How do I correct it?

Comment: You already have a dictionary. Why do you need to name each string accordingly ? Just access your dataframes using `dict['demand']` or `dict['supply']`. (Also, do not name your variable `dict` because it overrides python builtin `dict`)

Comment: Are demand_df, supply_df etc. strings? or variables

Comment: @RafaelC I am using these dataframes in pandasql's sqldf function. It gives an error if I use dict['demand'].

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe

Comment: @Karvy1 Sorry but I didn't read that you're using Pandas. Can you verify if my answer works under your 'panda dataframes'?

Comment: Commented to your answer, mate!

Answer (score 0):

First, do **not** name variables after built-ins, e.g. use `d` instead of `dict` and `lst` instead of `list`.

Second, do **not** dynamically name variables. It is poor practice, makes your code intractable, clutters the namespace, removes the connection between related variables.

Just access a dictionary value directly:

```
d = {'demand': demand_df, 'supply':supply_df, 'prod': prod_df}

d['demand']  # retrieve demand_df
```

There is, in my experience, no reason to dynamically name a dictionary value.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I needed that for using dictionary values in pandasql. I have created a seperate question to address that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686216/using-dictionary-values-in-pandasql

Comment: Excellent. Context is key here, and you've given it in your new question. thanks.