# Using dictionary values in pandasql

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pandasql

I have a dictionary that has dataframes in values, something like this -

```
mydict = {'demand': demand_df, 'supply':supply_df, 'prod': prod_df}
```

Then I am using `pandasql` module to execute a simple query.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM mydict['demand']"
print(ps.sqldf(query))
```

This is giving out an error -

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'
```

However, if I add an extra step, it does work -

```
demand = mydict['demand']
query = "SELECT * FROM demand"
print(ps.sqldf(query))
```

How do I work with the first option above?

Comment: I take it that `pandasql` is a requirement? I.e. you cannot switch to regular Pandas methods?

Comment: @jpp Are you referring to `merge` function in `pandas`? If yes, `pandasql` comes handy when I am making sql joins with multiple tables involving renaming column names.

Comment: I'm talking about any functionality you currently use. `pandasql` won't work with dictionary indexing within strings, you are left with messy string manipulation. What you have is probably the best you can hope.

Comment: Okay, so I will jave to live with this then!