# Converted Nested Dict to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I got the data which has nested dict inside.

I am trying to use `json_normalize` to convert into dataframe, but I got an error.

```
d = ['{"appMetadata": {"index": "cfs_ccs_eddi_35725", "host": "iaasn00009634", "job": "splunk_scraper"}, "timestampEpochSecond": 1545172308711, "metricTags": {"source": "/local/apps/eddi/presentment/logs/eddi-http-presentment-requests.log"}, "metricName": "splunk.logs.tstats.count.per.min", "metricValue": 5, "metricType": "count"}']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): d[i][j] 
                             for i in d.keys() 
                             for j in d[i].keys()},
                            orient='index')
```

The error is:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: d is a list not a dict, the dict is a string inside your list

Comment: The string can be accessed using `d[0]`

Comment: Have you tried this @david https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752256/bytes-list-of-dictionary-convert-to-dataframe? ;)

Comment: hi W-B, the data I use request.get from url, it is a list

Comment: Hi Ayorgo, thank you so much for the help, I tried, it didn't because the data type now changed to list, not sure how to apply your help before. the error I got is TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @david, no worries. It was a list of bytes the last time, now it seems to be the list of strings. You can apply the very same thing omitting the first step of `list_of_string = list(map(lambda d: d.decode('utf-8'), data))`

Comment: to get it out of a list to a dict just do:  `for x in d: loaded_json = json.loads(x)`

Comment: Hi @ ayogo, I got the error shows AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Also when  I apply list_of_dicts = list(map(literal_eval, d)) df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts), the new error is TypeError: Expected list, got dict

Comment: What I meant @david is that you need to copy the code from the previous answer but not the first line with `decode`.

Comment: Hi @ ayorgo, you are right, when I first run the code it works, however, when I go back to rerun to check and it shows error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Basically you change the first line from the other answer to `list_of_string = d` and carry on with the rest.

Comment: Thank you for the help Ayoro,   it has this error 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Hi Ayorgo, I found the error, it is because my data from URL some of them are dict, some of them are list.  Your code works perfect for the list, but got error when the data type is dict.

Comment: You say you are trying to use `json_normalize` but i don't see it anywhere in your question...

Answer (score 0):

convert your d list into dict

```
d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(l)] * 2, fillvalue=""))
```

Answer (score 0):

### You have a `list` with a `str` inside, not a `dict` or `json`:

- Note that the `dict` part of the data shown, is surrounded by quotes `['{bunch_of_stuff}']`
- That can be fixed with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

#### Data:

```py
d = ['{"appMetadata": {"index": "cfs_ccs_eddi_35725", "host": "iaasn00009634", "job": "splunk_scraper"}, "timestampEpochSecond": 1545172308711, "metricTags": {"source": "/local/apps/eddi/presentment/logs/eddi-http-presentment-requests.log"}, "metricName": "splunk.logs.tstats.count.per.min", "metricValue": 5, "metricType": "count"}']
```

#### Code:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

d = literal_eval(d[0])

print(d)
```

#### Output of fixed `d`:

```py
{'appMetadata': {'index': 'cfs_ccs_eddi_35725',
  'host': 'iaasn00009634',
  'job': 'splunk_scraper'},
 'timestampEpochSecond': 1545172308711,
 'metricTags': {'source': '/local/apps/eddi/presentment/logs/eddi-http-presentment-requests.log'},
 'metricName': 'splunk.logs.tstats.count.per.min',
 'metricValue': 5,
 'metricType': 'count'}
```

#### [`pandas.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```py
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

df = json_normalize(d)

print(df)
```

#### Output of `df`:

```py
 timestampEpochSecond                        metricName  metricValue metricType   appMetadata.index appMetadata.host appMetadata.job                                                     metricTags.source
        1545172308711  splunk.logs.tstats.count.per.min            5      count  cfs_ccs_eddi_35725    iaasn00009634  splunk_scraper  /local/apps/eddi/presentment/logs/eddi-http-presentment-requests.log
```