# I have data in one column, how to extract that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

Ihave data in one column, how to extract that?

For example:
     Shape_attribute is col name
    {"name":"circle","cx":371,"cy":2921,"r":73}
    {"name":"circle","cx":3712,"cy":29212,"r":73}
    {"name":"circle","cx":371,"cy":2921,"r":73}

I want output as follows:

```
name  cx  cy  r
circle 371 2921 73
circle 3712 29212 73
circle 371 2921 73
```

Note: all 4 values are in same column `shape_attributes`

Comment: are you saying you have a column full of dictionary?

Comment: @Shikha: the below answer Worked??

Comment: `pd.Series({"name":"circle","cx":371,"cy":2921,"r":73})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting dictionary/list inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
df_final = pd.concat([df, df['shape_attributes'].apply(pd.Series)], axis = 1).drop('shape_attributes', axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a dictionary of your values and then pass them to your Pandas Dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict={"name":"circle","cx":371,"cy":2921,"r":73}
df=pd.DataFrame([my_dict],columns=my_dict.keys())
```

Also to learn more about converting dictionary to dataframe, visit this [Dictionary to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.x

## Without dataframe

```
dict = {"name":"circle","cx":371,"cy":2921,"r":73}
keys= []
values = []
for key, value in dict.items():
    keys.append(str(key))
    values.append(str(value))
data = [keys, values]

for row in data: # Align right
    print("{: >10} {: >10} {: >10} {: >10}".format(*row))

for row in data: # Align left
    print("{: <10} {: <10} {: <10} {: <10}".format(*row))
```

or:

## With dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data={"name":"circle","cx":371,"cy":2921,"r":73}
df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=data.keys())
#Remove index
result = df.to_string(index=False)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Series from the dict, convert to a DataFrame and then Transpose:

```
d = {"name":"circle","cx":371,"cy":2921,"r":73}

pd.Series(d).to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
     name   cx    cy   r
0  circle  371  2921  73
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply pd.Series to the the column containing the dictionaries:

```
result = df['target_column'].apply(pd.Series)
```