# From nested dict to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I would like to convert nested dict to DataFrame object. I have a dictionary:

```
{
'David X': {
            'something1': 'string1'
            'something2': 'string2'
            'something3': 'string3'
            },
'David Y': {
            'something1': 'str1'
            'something2': 'str2'
            'something3': 'str3'
            }
}
```

I would like to obtain DataFrame object with rows consist of names, columns consist of 'something {1,2,3}' and appropriate values.

Comment: Related: [Converting list of dictionaries to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20638006/4909087)

Comment: This should be a duplicate one [would be duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary)

Comment: Here is [another duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
print (df)
        something1 something2 something3
David X    string1    string2    string3
David Y       str1       str2       str3
```

Comment: For transposed solution, use `orient='columns'`.