# From dict to pandas dataframe as rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am sure i must be missing something basic here. But as far as I know you can create a dataframe from a dict with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`. But I am not sure how it can be set that key-values pairs in a dict can be put it as rows in a dataframe.

For instance, given this example

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2}
```

the desired output would be:

```
    col1 col2
0    a     1
1    b     2
```

I know that the index might be a problem but that can be handle it with a simple `index = [0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should help you.

```
d = {k: [l] for k, l in d.items()}
pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'col1', 0: 'col2'})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Duplicate of Convert Python dict into a dataframe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe)

Simple answer for python 3.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'a':1,'b':2, 'c':3}
df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns = ['cola','colb'])
```

Comment: Weird, I was writing the same solution, but it keeps giving me an error: `'list' object is not callable`

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? The d.items() only needs to be converted to a list in Python 3 I believe.

Comment: Using python 3.7. Very weird, might post this as question.