# Creating a dataframe with lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I would like to create a dataframe from 2 python lists that I have.

Say I have the following 2 lists;

```py
x = [1,2,3]
z = ['a','v','d']
```

I have initialized a dataframe

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Type', 'Data']
```

and this is one of the things that I have tried doing.

```py
df = data.append({'Type': x, 'Data' : z}, ignore_index = True)
```

but it results in the following dataframe

```py
   Type       Data
0 [1, 2, 3]  [a, v, d]
```

However, this is what I actually want it to look like

```py
   Type    Data
0  1      a
1  2      v
2  3      d
```

How would I do this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'Type': x, 'Data' : z})`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python dict into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert dictionary to `DataFrame`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Type', 'Data'])
df = data.append(pd.DataFrame({'Type': x, 'Data' : z}), ignore_index = True)
print (df)
  Type Data
0    1    a
1    2    v
2    3    d
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted. But now I'm just not sure how I would append to this dataframe. Say I want to add r = [5,6,7] to Type and w = [r,t,w] to Data in the same way. How would I do this?

Comment: @Susan-l3p - You can again call `df = data.append(pd.DataFrame({'Type': x, 'Data' : z}), ignore_index = True)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
df =  pd.DataFrame(zip(x,z),columns=['Type', 'Data'])
print(df)
```

**Output** :

```
   Type Data
0     1    a
1     2    v
2     3    d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use assign:

```
data.assign(Type=x, Data=z)

  Type  Data
0   1   a
1   2   v
2   3   d
```