# How can I fix a data frame so that it has more than one row?

Tags: python

I have a list with words and the frequency of these, I want to convert that list to a dataframe.  but with my code I get a dataframe of 1 row * 901 columns. I would like to know how I could do it to have more than one row and two columns that calls 'Word', 'Frequency'. 
Thank you!

```py
Music={}
for words in frequency_list:
    Music[words]=frequency[words]
    print(Music)


df = DataFrame(Music, dtype='str', index=[0 ])

print (df)
```

I expect a data frame with many rows and two columns, 
but the actual output is [1 rows x 901 columns].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python dict into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe)

Comment: Try: `df = DataFrame(list(Music.items()), columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])`