# scraping from each table based on dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data https://www.bps.go.id/indicator/3/1/25/inflasi-umum-.html from 1995-to this day,is there any way i can do it? i'm stuck because each year have spesific table and different html. Thank you in advance
[image: table visual]

Comment: The ```lxml``` and ```beautifulsoup``` libraries might be useful.

Comment: can i do it one time? or i must scrape every html bcs each date have different html

Comment: I think once for each page should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, extract the options value from the `select` tag to get the url for each year :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

baseUrl = "https://www.bps.go.id"
dateFrom = 1995
dateTo = 2019

#get the options 
r = requests.get(f"{baseUrl}/indicator/3/1/25/inflasi-umum-.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
years = dict([
    (t.text, t["value"]) 
    for t in soup.find("select").findAll("option") 
    if t.get("value")
])
```

And then iterate through your range for each year, and use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to extract the table so you have a dictionnary with key as year and [Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html#dataframe) as value :

```
#iterate through years
data = {}
ranges = range(dateFrom, dateTo + 1)
for n in ranges:
  print(f"get data for year {n}")
  r = requests.get(f"{baseUrl}{years[str(n)]}")
  table = pd.read_html(r.text)
  data[str(n)] = table[2]

print(data)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeBadanPusakStats)

Comment: thank you so much! can i ask,why year have to be dict?? can i change it to something else?

Comment: In the code bave years is like `{ "2019": "/......." }` so that you can use years["2019"] in the loop to get the path value directly but you can also make an array if you want

Comment: okay thank! one more question,do you have an idea to delete the very first output, its because i want to convert it to csv .sorry for bother you =>[             0   1
0  DATA SENSUS NaN,     0         1   2          3
0 NaN  Facebook NaN  Instagram
1 NaN   Twitter NaN    Youtube

Comment: I've updated the code above with table[2] to get only the table without the header

Comment: umm..sorry can i ask one more question?,i've been trying to  convert dict to dataframe,but it always error same goes with saving to csv,can you help me once again

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18837262/2614364)