# Flatten dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, explode

DO NOT MARK THIS AS DUPLICATE.

This is my dictionary, `test_dict`:

```
{"Report" : {
      "ReportHeader": {
      "ReportNum": None,
      "Type": {
        "source": "user",
        "text": "Training"
      },
      "Reg": "WWWWWW"
    }
}
}
```

I want to flatten as a dataframe where the expected output is:

```
    Report.ReportHeader.ReportNum     Report.ReportHeader.Type.source          Report.ReportHeader.Type.text     Report.ReportHeader.Reg 

                None                        User                                           Training                            WWWWWWW
```

What I've done so far :

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict)
```

Producing this in Dataframe:

```
                                              Report
ReportHeader  {'ReportNum': None, 'Type': {'source': ...
```

I also try to `explode`:

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame(test_dict).explode('Report').reset_index(drop=True)
```

But I'm not getting the desired output. Instead getting `KeyError:0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Python dict into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe)

Comment: No @anddt clearly not, the duplicate dictionary is flat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {"Report" : {
      "ReportHeader": {
      "ReportNum": None,
      "Type": {
        "source": "user",
        "text": "Training"
      },
      "Reg": "WWWWWW"
    }
}
}

df = pd.json_normalize(d)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Report.ReportHeader.ReportNum Report.ReportHeader.Type.source Report.ReportHeader.Type.text Report.ReportHeader.Reg
0                          None                            user                      Training                  WWWWWW
```