# Pandas create a column for each element of a list in a dictionary value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary where the values are lists like the following:

```
d= {u'2012-06-08': [list_element_0, list_element_1, list_element_2],
 u'2012-06-09': [list_element_0, list_element_1, list_element_2],
 u'2012-06-10': [list_element_0, list_element_1, list_element_2]}
```

I'd like to create a `dataframe` for with 4 columns: `[column_for_dict_keys, column_for_elements_in_list_at_index_0, column_for_elements_in_list_at_index_1, column_for_elements_in_list_at_index_2]`

I found how to make a regular dictionary into a dataframe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe), but I don't know how to modify it for my specific case

Comment: Please share the expected output based on the sample input you shared.

Comment: From what I understood, try `pd.DataFrame(data = [[key, *value] for key, value in d.items()], columns = ['column_for_dict_keys', 'column_for_elements_in_list_at_index_0', 'column_for_elements_in_list_at_index_1', 'column_for_elements_in_list_at_index_2'])` which will create a DataFrame with four columns using your dict keys and values as data.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        index               0               1               2
0  2012-06-08  list_element_0  list_element_1  list_element_2
1  2012-06-09  list_element_0  list_element_1  list_element_2
2  2012-06-10  list_element_0  list_element_1  list_element_2
```