# Expand column in dataframe based on subvalues (opposite of group by?)

Tags: python, pandas, join

Let’s say I have a dataframe. I want to take the values in col1 (`A` for example) and return multiple more values like `A.1`, `A.2`, `A.3` etc.

Each of the values in this column correspond to groups of data elsewhere. I want run a custom function that returns a list of values for these and I want to create a new dataframe with new rows identical to the original row except with the values changed in `col1`:

So:

```py
Col1, Col2, Col3
A, 55, type
```

If `A` corresponds to a list such as `AB`, `AJ`, `AI` I want a new dataframe:

```py
Col1,Col2,Col3
AB, 55, type
AJ, 55, type,
AI, 55, type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the mapping between the `col1`s is contained in a dict e.g.

```py
mapping = {'AB':'A', 'AJ':'A', 'AI':'A'}
```

Then you can [create a new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe) of the mapping and join this to the original table:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A'], 'Col2':[55], 'Col3':['type']})
df_map = pd.DataFrame(mapping.items(), columns=['Col1_new', 'Col1'])

df_new = pd.merge(df, df_map)
```

```py
  Col1  Col2  Col3 Col1_new
0    A    55  type       AB
1    A    55  type       AJ
2    A    55  type       AI
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# define the two tables
a = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A'], 'Col2':[55], 'Col3':['type']})
b = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['AB', 'AJ', 'AI']})

# Create a column in your second table that matches `Col1` in your first table
# it appears you want that to be the first letter of `Col1` in table `b`:
b['key'] = b['Col1'].str[0]

# Join the two tables together on that key that matches across both
df = a.set_index('Col1').join(b.set_index('key'))

# Rearrange as you like:
df = df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']]
```

Gives `df` = :

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3
A   AB    55  type
A   AJ    55  type
A   AI    55  type
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
l = list('BJI')
df.iloc[[0]*len(l)].assign(Col1 = lambda x: x['Col1'].str.cat(l)).reset_index()
```