# Converting dictionary into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**tried this:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(sample.items()),columns = ['id','age','chest_pain_type',
        'blood_sugar','rest_electro','max_heart_rate', 'exercice_angina','rest_blood_pressure'])
```

**Got this:**
8 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns
**and the error is occuring in this line:**

```
columns = _validate_or_indexify_columns(content, columns)
```

**the dictionary 'sample':**

```
    {'age': '34', 'max_heart_rate': '123', 'rest_blood_pressure': '132',
     'blood_sugar': '1', 'exercice_angina': '0', 'chest_pain_type': 'typ_angina',
 'rest_electro': 'normal', 'id': 8808}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46577585/2901002) - `df = pd.DataFrame([sample],columns = ['id','age','chest_pain_type',
        'blood_sugar','rest_electro','max_heart_rate', 'exercice_angina','rest_blood_pressure']) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using all scalar values, you must pass an index

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': '34', 'max_heart_rate': '123', 'rest_blood_pressure': '132',
     'blood_sugar': '1', 'exercice_angina': '0', 'chest_pain_type': 'typ_angina',
 'rest_electro': 'normal', 'id': 8808},index = [0])


    age max_heart_rate  rest_blood_pressure blood_sugar exercice_angina chest_pain_type rest_electro    id
0   34    123                  132              1             0    typ_angina   normal  8808
```