# How to filter and sort div tags from an html page?

Tags: python, html, pdf, pdfminer

I'm trying to read pdf table using `pdfminer` following the post: [Python: An easy way to extract data from PDF tables](https://medium.com/@winston.smith.spb/python-an-easy-way-to-extract-data-from-pdf-tables-c8de22308341).

My pdf table is formatted as below:

[image: screenshot of PDF table]

My python code is:

```
from io import StringIO
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text_to_fp
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
import re
from pprint import pprint

output=StringIO()
with open('1065 tax code list.pdf','rb') as pdf_file:
 extract_text_to_fp(pdf_file,output,laparams=LAParams(),
 output_type='html',codec=None)

raw_html=output.getvalue()
Link_left_boder = 78
Link_right_border =147
from lxml import html

tree=html.fromstring(raw_html)
divs=tree.xpath('.//div')

filtered_divs={'Link':[]}

for div in divs: 
 div_style = div.get('style')
 try: 
    left=re.findall(r'left:([0-9]+)px',div_style)[0]
 except IndexError:
    continue
 if Link_left_boder<=int(left)<Link_right_border:
    filtered_divs['Link'].append(div.text_content().strip('\n'))
  
print(filtered_divs)
```

The result is: 
`{'Link': ['Link', '01A\n01AA\n01B\n01BB\n04\n05\n06\n06.A\n07\n07.01\n07.02\n07.03\n07.04\n07.05\n07.06\n07.07\n07.08\n07.09\n07.10\n07.11\n07.12\n07.13\n07.14\n07.15\n07.16\n07.17\n07.18\n07.19\n07.20\n07.21\n07.22\n07.23\n07.24\n07.25\n07.26\n07.27\n07.28\n07.29\n07.30\n07.31\n07.32\n07.33\n07.34\n07.35\n07.36\n07.37\n07.38\n07.39',...}}`

How can I fix the code so the result will be? 
`{'Link': ['Link','01A','01AA','01B','01BB','04'...]}`?

Comment: ```x='01A\n01AA\n01B\n01BB\n04\n05\n06\n06.A\n07\n07.01'```, ```x.split("\n")```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I got {"Link":[['Link',' '],['01A','01AA',...],['Link',' '],['07.40','07.41',...]]}. From there, how do I convert the dictionary to dataframe? I tried:
 data=[]
for row in filtered_divs['Link']: 
    if'Link' in row[0]:
        continue
    data_row={'Link': row[0].split(' ')[0]}
    data.append(data_row)
#print(data)
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
it only converts the first row to dataframe and how to modify the loop so it converts all the data in the dictionary? 
Thank you!

Comment: ```filtered_divs['Link'][1] = filtered_divs['Link'][1].split('\n')```. then what? what are you trying to accomplish? what would the final dataframe look like? please edit the question and add the necessary info

Comment: I'm trying to convert the dictionary filtered_divs to dataframe as below: 
Link
01A
01AA
01B
...

Comment: you mean something like [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46577585/4935162)

Comment: I appreciate your attempt but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I tried the code below and it works: 
'data=[]
for row in zip (filtered_divs['Link']): 
     if'Link' in row[0]:
         continue
     data_row={'Link': row[0]}
     data.append(data_row)
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df2=df['Link'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).to_frame('Link')'

Thanks.