# Convert Python 3D dict into a dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've read excel file using `pd.read_excel` and i also have specified from which sheets i want them using Regex.

```
def gettingSheetName(_directory,_regex):
    '''reads the file using regex as a pattern for Sheet name'''
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(_directory)
    regex = re.compile(_regex)
    sheets = [n for n in xl.sheet_names if regex.match(n)]
    if sheets:
        return pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=sheets,index_col=False)
```

Therefor in return i get a Dictionary with 3 Dimensions.

```
{'SheetName':      Col1                 Col2
0             27                someText
1             35                someText
..           ...                         ...
171         4444                someText
172         6666                someText
```

i've tried `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dic)` to convert this to Pandas Data frame. and i got this error

> If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

i also tried [this code that i found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe) `pd.DataFrame(list(Sach.items()), columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])` but the resualt looks like this

```
    Col1       col2
0   Sheetname  Col1 Col2 0....
```

Sheet name goes to value and after that Columns and finally the values that i'm assuming are starting with the first index which was 0
I've search everywhere and all i could find was for 2D Dic which doesn't consider the Sheet name.
although i used this for loop instead of other popular methods which does the job, my Question is is there any way that i can use a Pandas function to achieve this? or possibly can i **Not** take the Sheetname from the beginning?

```
for key in Dic:
     Dic=Dic[key]
```

**EDIT 1:**

so after using `return pd.concat(pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=sheets,index_col=False))` and then `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Sach)` i got  this Data Frame which is almost what i wanted but i only need the Cols and Values

```
                 Col1    Col2
Sheetname   0    Val1    Val2
            1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
return pd.concat(pd.read_excel(xl,sheet_name=sheets,index_col=False)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
d = {'SheetName':  pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[27,25], 'Col2':list('ab')}),
     'SheetName1':  pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[270,205], 'Col2':list('th')})} 
print (d)
{'SheetName':    Col1 Col2
0    27    a
1    25    b, 'SheetName1':    Col1 Col2
0   270    t
1   205    h}
```

By default get `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.concat(d)
print (df)
              Col1 Col2
SheetName  0    27    a
           1    25    b
SheetName1 0   270    t
           1   205    h
```

For convert it to column use:

```
df = pd.concat(d).droplevel(1).rename_axis('sheets').reset_index()
print (df)
       sheets  Col1 Col2
0   SheetName    27    a
1   SheetName    25    b
2  SheetName1   270    t
3  SheetName1   205    h
```

For remove `MultiIndex` use:

```
df = pd.concat(d).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Col1 Col2
0    27    a
1    25    b
2   270    t
3   205    h
```

Comment: actually i don't need the Sheetname at all. just the Col and Values are important 
tnx for quick response

Comment: when i used  ```
pd.concat(pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=sheets,index_col=False))
```
and then pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dic) i almost got what i wanted but i'll edit my Question so i can better demonstrate

Comment: TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - so `pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=sheets,index_col=False)` return correct DataFrame? It is not dict?

Comment: no it's a <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - Use `d = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=sheets,index_col=False)
    pd.concat(d).reset_index(drop=True)` instead `return pd.concat(pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=sheets,index_col=False)) and then pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Sach)`

Comment: Or one row `return pd.concat(pd.read_excel(xl,sheet_name=sheets,index_col=False)).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: tnx a lot. if you Could Explain more and if you Could  provide more detail for future readers, it would be greate

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - sure, added some links to docs. There is also added some sample of dict for explain how it working.