# Pandas, read Length only of all pickle files in directory

Tags: python, pandas

I read a bunch of pickle files with the below code, I want to loop through and get each of these, identify the length of each file. Ie how many records.

Two issues:

1. Concat will combine all my dfs into one, which takes a long time. Anyone to just read the len?
2. If Concat is the way to go, how can I get the length of each file if they all go into one dataframe? I guess the problem is here to identify where each file stops and starts. I could add a column to identify each filename and count there I suspect.

What ive tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os


files = glob.glob('O:\Stack\Over\Flow\*.pkl')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(fp, compression='xz').assign(New=os.path.basename(fp)) for fp in files])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for, do you _also_ want the concatenated dataframe at the end or _only_ a list of all of the individual df lengths?

Comment: Sorry, individual DF lengths.

Answer (score 2):

Append to a list first then pd.concat due to [quadratic copying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/6361531) undesired effects of appending or concatenating inside a for loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os

files = glob.glob('O:\Stack\Over\Flow\*.pkl')

dfs = []

for fp in files:
    df = pd.read_pickle(fp, compression='xz').assign(New=os.path.basename(fp)) 
    dfs.append(df)
    # or as @G.Anderson points out maybe
    dfs.append(len(df))

pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing and I could be wrong, but the way I read it OP doesn't actually want the DFs at the end, they just want the length of each. So `dfs.append(df)` -> `dfs.append(len(df))` and eschew the `concat` altogether

Comment: @G.Anderson You could be right. I agree.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the lengths of individual dataframes, then the call to `concat` is entirely unnecessary overhead. To repurpose your own code, you're already building the dataframes from the files, you can just use those to capture only the lengths.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os


files = glob.glob('O:\Stack\Over\Flow\*.pkl')

#a call to assign should also be irrelevant because adding a column doesn't change the length
lens=[len(pd.read_pickle(fp, compression='xz')) for fp in files]
```

Or if you want to keep a dictionary of the filename with the length this should work:

```
lens = {os.path.basename(fp):len(pd.read_pickle(fp, compression='xz')) for fp in files}
```

Comment: thanks Gary! this is what i am looking for ! although Lens doesnt have the file name, so I am not sure which length belongs to which file.

Comment: See the edit, using a dictionary comprehension instead of a list comprehension

Comment: thanks! how would I convert this to a dataframe?

Comment: [Convert python dictionary into a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe)