# Provide sample DataFrame from csv file

Tags: python, pandas

when asking a python/pandas question on stackoverflow I often like to provide a sample dataframe.
I usually have a local csv file I deal with for testing.

So for a DataFrame I like to provide a code in my question like

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Is there an easy way or tool to get a csv file into code in a format like this, so another user can easily recreate the dataframe?

For now I usually do it manually, which is annoying and time consuming. I have to copy/paste the data from excel to stackoverflow, remove tabs/spaces, rearrange numbers to get a list or dictionary and so on.

Example csv file:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

I if want to provide this table I can provide code like:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I will have to create the dictionary and Dataframe manually. I manually have to write the code into the stackoverflow editor.
For a more complex table this could lead to a lot of work.

Hope you get the "problem".

Comment: read your csv with `pd.read_csv` and export the df to dictionary with [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: well....that was easy...thank you

Comment: Good question. Supposed duplicate does not answer this question.

Comment: See: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56032131#56032131 (using `StringIO()` and `pd.read_csv()`) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57343119/4539999

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [`dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) from the `.csv` and pass it to the [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html) *constructor* :

```
N = 5 # <- adjust here to choose the number of rows

dico = pd.read_csv("f.csv").sample(N).to_dict("list")

S = f"df = pd.DataFrame{dico}") # <- copy its output and paste in StackOverflow
```

You can also use [`pyperclip`](https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to copy directly the text you'll paste/include on your question :

```
#pip install pyperclip
import pyperclip

pyperclip.copy(S)
```