# 'ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index' when creating dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been learning Python recently, and was working with Pandas when this error came up:

```
import pandas 

students = {"Adi": 32, "Ron" : 64, "Jonny": 34} 

student_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(students) # <--- error

print(student_dataframe) # this will only print table
```

The error:

```
student_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(students) 
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index' when creating dataframe
```

When I click on error location it takes me to source code of Pandas (I think?) and shows an error. It was working just fine a few days back... how do I fix it? Is the source code the problem or have I missed something?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please make sure you search on Google before you ask a question here. Here is a good StackOverflow post that already answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837262/convert-python-dict-into-a-dataframe

Comment: @Mark, it should actually be `pandas.DataFrame(students.items())`

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: The question's code is trying to create 3 columns named `Adi`, `Ron` and `Jonny`, with a single value in each. I doubt that's what you really wanted

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, `pandas` is imported as `pd`, and `DataFrame` is a class, so you should be using parentheses, not brackets. It is also usually more standard to pass the different columns as arrays for each key in a dict, so that you have column names:

```
import pandas as pd

students = {"students":["Adi", "Ron", "Jonny"], "scores": [32,64,34]} 

student_df = pd.DataFrame(students)

print(student_df)
```